# How can I show folders and files in a TreeView?

Tags: html, css, treeview, jstree

I want to fill the folder and files into html treeview and I want to show the creation date and extensions of the files. How can I do that?
my treeview html :

```html
<ul>
<li>
    Main Folder
    <ul>
        <li data-jstree='{ "opened" : true }'>
            Folder 1
            <ul>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file" }'>
                    File1 - Created Date: 03_04_2018
                </li>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file" }'>
                    File2 - Created Date: 03_04_2018
                </li>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file" }'>
                    File3 - Created Date: 03_04_2018
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-jstree='{ "opened" : true }'>
            Folder 2
            <ul>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file" }'>
                    File1 - Created Date: 03_04_2018
                </li>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file" }'>
                    File2 - Created Date: 03_04_2018
                </li>
                <li data-jstree='{ "type" : "file" }'>
                    File3 - Created Date: 03_04_2018
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[Treeview Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNNQQ.png)

Comment: Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow.

Comment: I have to agree with the comment by @IgorYalovoy. Without any example code, you will likely not get answers that are helpful to your specific problem. Is this `TreeView` a custom component that you have created? If so, we cannot guess at how it has been implemented.

Comment: It appears that your question is specific to the jstree jQuery plugin rather than to .net core

Comment: please check this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/nested-expandable-folders/